# Linq-to-objects: creating a two-level hierarchy from a flat source

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Let's say I have this simple structure

```
class FooDefinition
{
    public FooDefinition Parent { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    public FooDefinition Definition { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

A `Bar` has a list of `Foos` which can be simple (no parent/child relationships) or nested just one level (i.e. a parent `Foo` has many child `Foos`). As can be seen here, the relationships are specified in the `FooDefinition`, not the `Foo itself`.

What I need to do is generate a list of `Foos` properly grouped by this hierarchy. Consider the following source data:

```
var simpleDefinition = new FooDefinition();
var parentDefinition = new FooDefinition();
var childDefinition = new FooDefinition { Parent = parentDefinition };

var bar = new Bar { Foos = new[]
                           {
                               new Foo { Definition = simpleDefinition },
                               new Foo { Definition = parentDefinition },
                               new Foo { Definition = childDefinition }
                           }};
```

I'd like to get a collection of top-level items with their chilren. An adequate data structure would probably be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Foo, Foo>>`.

The result would look like:

- Item 1 (simple)
- Item 2 (parent)

  - Item 3 (child)

And of course I'd like to do this with a purely-functional Linq query. I do lots of these, but my brain seems to be stuck today.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the edit; I had left the original names inadvertently.

Comment: No problem. Please wait before commenting my answer. I found the problem with it already.

Comment: Fixed my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bar.Foos.Where(x => x.Definition.Parent == null)
        .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x, 
                                  bar.Foos.Where(c => c.Definition
                                                       .Parent == x.Definition
                                                )));
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<Tuple<Foo, IEnumerable<Foo>>>`, where `Item2` of the `Tuple` contains the children for the parent in `Item1`. For your example, this returns two Tuples:

- `Item1 = simpleDefinition` and `Item2` containing an empty enumerable
- `Item1 = parentDefinition` and `Item2` containing an enumerable which contains `childDefinition`

There might be a more elegant or faster way, but I couldn't come up with it...

Oh well, I contradict my own comment a little bit with this, but it is possible with `GroupBy` - at least nearly:

```
bar.Foos.Where(x => x.Definition.Parent == null)
        .GroupBy(x => x,
                 x => bar.Foos.Where(c => c.Definition.Parent == x.Definition));
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Foo, IEnumerable<Foo>>>`.

Update:
I wanted to know, if the solution you wanted is possible at all.
Yes, it is:

```
bar.Foos.Where(x => x.Definition.Parent != null)
        .GroupBy(x => bar.Foos.Where(y => y.Definition == x.Definition.Parent)
                              .Single(),
                 x => x)
        .Union(bar.Foos.Where(x => x.Definition.Parent == null && 
                                   !bar.Foos.Any(c => c.Definition.Parent == 
                                                      x.Definition))
                       .GroupBy(x => x, x => (Foo)null));
```

But I really don't want to know the *big O* of this and it really shouldn't be used ;-)

Comment: I did get there, but I'd really like an `IGrouping<Foo, Foo>` instead of a `Tuple<Foo, IEnumerable<Foo>>`

Comment: Why do you want to have an `IGrouping`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: because iterating on the IGrouping is "prettier" than doin it on Item2 (and, since these are actually called Items, it's less confusing for the reader)

Comment: @Diego: A grouping doesn't make too much sense, because a group always has a key **and** a list of associated values that is not empty. But you want to have a key without associated values (the case of `simpleDefinition`). This just doesn't match.

Comment: I was playing with a similar solution, but note that if you remove `new Foo { Definition = parentDefinition }` from `bar.Foos`, then the `Foo` using `childDefinition` will no longer make it into the result. In that case, should the `Definitions` of the  `Foos` in `Bar` be walked until the top-level is found, or should the `Foo` using `childDefinition` be excluded since the top-level item isn't itself in `bar.Foos`?

Comment: @Diego: I added a solution that at least returns something close to what you want to have.

Comment: @Daniel +1 by the way...my previous comment was not meant to disparage your solution but only to clarify the requirement for another test case.

Comment: @druttka: I wasn't offended by your comment, quite the contrary. If this IS a requirement of @Diego, my solution won't work and a recursive approach would be much better.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: that's not entirely true; the list of items can be empty (look at ILookup<TKey, TElement>, which implements IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> - but yeah, this is the part that gives me headaches. Regarding your second comment: assume there's only one level, and that there's always a Foo for every FooDefinition.

Comment: @Diego: Did you check my latest update? I think this is as close as it gets. And I know that it isn't entirely true, otherwise my update wouldn't be possible ;-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: oh, well, I think I'll go with the Tuple solution. BTW, by "your second comment" I actually mean @druttka's (I misread the sender)

Comment: @Diego: I think that's the best way. To get an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Foo, Foo>>` you would need a `GroupByMany` method...

Comment: @Diego: I just couldn't stop trying to find a solution. And I found one! ;-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I love the fact that you didn't give up :-) The problem with that solution (I did consider something very similar, but using DefaultIfEmpty) is that the collection isn't really empty: it has a null element.

Comment: @Diego: Yes, that's what I meant with my comment that your requirement and `IGrouping` don't match. I am pretty sure, that you can't create a call to `GroupBy` that will return an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` with an empty collection in one or more of the `IGrouping`s. Because that's the nature of `GroupBy`: For every element in the source collection there will be an entry in the collection of the `IGrouping`. Your requirement is "upside down".

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class and a method, you can get to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Foo,Foo>>`.

```
    class FooRelation{
        public Foo Parent {get; set;}
        public Foo Child  {get; set;}
    }

    static IEnumerable<FooRelation> GetChildren(Bar source, Foo parent){
        var children = source.Foos.Where(c => c.Definition.Parent == parent.Definition);
        if(children.Any())
            return children.Select(c => new FooRelation{Parent = parent, Child = c});
        return new FooRelation[]{new FooRelation{Parent = parent}};
    }
```

You might even be able to fold that static method into this query...but it would get messy:

```
     var r = bar.Foos.Where(x => x.Definition.Parent == null)
                .SelectMany(x => GetChildren(bar, x))
                .GroupBy(fr => fr.Parent, fr => fr.Child);
```